# How can I simplify/improve the performance of this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am very new to MySQL and thanks to the great support from you more experienced guys here I am managing to struggle by, while learning a lot in the process.

I have a query that does exactly what I want.  However, it looks extremely messy to me and I am certain there must be a way to simplify it.

How can this query be improved and optimized for performance?

Many thanks

```
            $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."

    FROM $sTable b 
    LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS projects_count, a.songs_id

   FROM $sTable2 a
   GROUP BY a.songs_id
) bb ON bb.songs_id = b.songsID

LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT AVG(rating) AS rating, COUNT(rating) AS ratings_count, c.songid

FROM $sTable3 c

   GROUP BY c.songid   
) bbb ON bbb.songid = b.songsID

LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT c.songid, c.userid,

    CASE WHEN EXISTS 
   ( 
       SELECT songid 
       FROM $sTable3
       WHERE songid = c.songid 
   ) Then 'User Voted'
   else
   (
       'Not Voted'
   )
   end
   AS voted
FROM $sTable3 c
WHERE c.userid = $userid


   GROUP BY c.songid   
) bbbb ON bbbb.songid = b.songsID
```

EDIT:  Here is a description of what the query is doing:-

I have three tables:

- $sTable = a table of songs (songid, mp3link, artwork, useruploadid
  etc.)
- $sTable2 = a table of projects with songs linked to them (projectid,
  songid, project name etc.)
- $sTable3 = a table of song ratings (songid, userid, rating)

All of this data is output to a JSON array and displayed in a table in my application to provide a list of songs, combined with the projects and ratings data.

The query itself does the following in this order:-

1. Collects all rows from $sTable
2. Joins to $sTable2 on songsID and counts the number of rows (projects) in this table which have the same songsID
3. Joins to $stable3 on songsID and works out an average of the column 'rating' in this table which have the same songsID
4. At this point it also counts the total number of rows in $sTable3 which have the same songID to provide a total number of votes.
5. Finally it performs a check on all these rows to see if the $userid (which is a variable containing the ID of the logged in user) matches the 'userid' stores in $sTable3 for each row in order to check whether a user has already voted on a given songID or not.  If it matches then it returns "User Voted" if not it returns "Not Voted".  It outputs this as a seperate column into my JSON array which I then check against clientside in my app and add a class to.

If there is any more detail anyone needs, please just let me know.  Thanks all.

EDIT:

Thanks to Aurimis' excellent first attempt I am closing in on a much more simple solution.

This is the code I have tried based on that suggestion.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."

    FROM 
      (SELECT 
        $sTable.songsID, COUNT(rating) AS ratings_count, 
        AVG(rating) AS ratings
      FROM $sTable 
        LEFT JOIN $sTable2 ON $sTable.songsID = $sTable2.songs_id
        LEFT JOIN $sTable3 ON $sTable.songsID = $sTable3.songid
      GROUP BY $sTable.songsID) AS A
    LEFT JOIN $sTable3 AS B ON A.songsID = B.songid AND B.userid = $userid
```

There are several problems however.  I had to remove the first line of your answer as it caused a 500 internal server error:

```
IF(B.userid = NULL, "Not voted", "User Voted") AS voted
```

Obviously now the 'voted check' functionality is lost.

Also and more importantly it is not returning all the columns defined in my array, only the songsID.  My JSON returns Unknown column 'song_name' in 'field list' - If I remov it from my $aColumns array it will of course move on to the next one.

I am defining my columns at the beginning of my script as this array is used for filtering and putting together the output for the JSON encode.  This is the definition of $aColumns:-

```
$aColumns = array( 'songsID', 'song_name', 'artist_band_name', 'author', 'song_artwork', 'song_file', 'genre', 'song_description', 'uploaded_time', 'emotion', 'tempo', 'user', 'happiness', 'instruments', 'similar_artists', 'play_count', 'projects_count',  'rating', 'ratings_count', 'voted');
```

In order to quickly test the rest of the query I modified the first line within the subquery to select $sTable.* rather than $sTable.songsID (remember $sTable is the songs table)

Then... The query obviously worked, but with terrible performance of course.  But only returned 24 songs out of the 5000 song test dataset.  Therefore I changed your first 'JOIN' to a 'LEFT JOIN' so that all 5000 songs were returned.  To clarify the query needs to return ALL of the rows in the songs table but with various extra bits of data from the projects and ratings tables for each song.

So... We are getting there and I am certain that this is a much better approach it just needs some modification.  Thanks for your help so far Aurimis.

Comment: it seems that the person who wrote the query was not new to MySQL

Comment: I wrote it myself by 'googling', asking various questions here, and reading up a lot. However I have in essence tacked several pieces together in to one 'working' query to achieve what I want. Although I understand what each part of the query does and why it works, I do not have the experience to know whether I am doing this in an effecient manner or not.  My instict from my experience with other languages tells me that I am not.  Therefore I would welcome the advice of more experienced MySQL developers. :)

Comment: Can you describe what the expected result should be?

Comment: I've just updated my original question to give you some more detail. Cheers.

Comment: could you post the create table statements of the tables. It would be useful to look at the indexes and the data types.

Comment: include index, and execution plan, please

Comment: Sorry guys... I've been away all weekend with my fiancee and wont be back until tomorrow morning. newtower has posted what looks to be a fantastic solution at first glance as an answer.  I'll be giving it a try tomorrow when i'm back.  If I still don't manage to get anwyehre I will post all create table statements and index/execution plan as requested.  Thanks for everything so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    songsID, song_name, artist_band_name, author, song_artwork, song_file,
    genre, song_description, uploaded_time, emotion, tempo,
    `user`, happiness, instruments, similar_artists, play_count,
    projects_count,
    rating, ratings_count,
    IF(user_ratings_count, 'User Voted', 'Not Voted') as voted
FROM (
    SELECT
        sp.songsID, projects_count,
        AVG(rating) as rating,
        COUNT(rating) AS ratings_count,
        COUNT(IF(userid=$userid, 1, NULL)) as user_ratings_count
    FROM (
        SELECT songsID, COUNT(*) as projects_count
        FROM $sTable s
        LEFT JOIN $sTable2 p ON s.songsID = p.songs_id
        GROUP BY songsID) as sp
    LEFT JOIN $sTable3 r ON sp.songsID = r.songid
    GROUP BY sp.songsID) as spr
JOIN $sTable s USING (songsID);
```

You will need the following indexes:

- (songs_id) on $sTable2
- the composite (songid, rating, userid) on $sTable3

the ideas behind the query:

- subqueries operate with INTs so that the result of the subquery would easily fit in memory
- left joins are grouped separately to reduce the cartesian product
- user votes are counted in the same subquery as other ratings to avoid expensive correlated subquery
- all othe information is retrieved ib the final join

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion newtover.  I won't be in a position to check your solution until after the weekend. From taking a quick look all seems good to me, i'll let you know on monday. :-)

Comment: Fantastic... It works perfectly. It is far simpler to understand and infinitely more elegant in terms of its execution.  I have yet to do any performance testing, but from initial impression it is certainly no worse and using your query will make any future adjustmenst far easier to manage as it is far superior structurally also.  Huge thanks newtover, a genuinely great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Let me try based on your description, not the query. I'll just use `Songs` to indicate `Table1`, `Projects` to indicate `Table2` and `Ratings` to indicate `Table3` - for clarity.

```
SELECT 
  /* [column list again] */,
  IF(B.userid = NULL, "Not voted", "Voted") as voted 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
    Songs.SongID, count(rating) as total_votes, 
    avg(rating) as average_rating /*[,.. other columns as you need them] */
  FROM Songs 
    JOIN Projects ON Songs.SongID = Projects.SongID
    LEFT JOIN Ratings ON Songs.SongID = Ratings.SongID
  GROUP BY Songs.SongID) as A
LEFT JOIN Ratings as B ON A.SongID = B.SongID AND B.userid = ? /* your user id */
```

As you see, you can get all the information on songs in one, relatively simple query (just using Group by and count() / avg() functions). To get the information whether a song was rated by a particular user requires a subquery - where you can do a LEFT JOIN, and if the userid is empty - you know he has not voted.

Now, I did not go through your query in depth, as it really looks complicated. Could be that I missed something - if that's the case, please update the description and I can try again :)

Comment: This looks great Aurimas, huge thank you for the suggestion.  I wont be in  position to test this for another hour or so.  I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Aurimas... I've updated my question with my findings since trying your suggestion.  cheers. :)